# Why does downloading the x86-64 python installer cause a 32 bit set up to occur on my PC?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

When i downloaded Windows x86 executable installer from this [python download link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/).

and run the file and I greeted with

[image]

Please see my PC description below

[image]

I cannot find posts of anybody else who has had this problem. I'm completely stumped as to why this happened?

Edit: I misunderstood the meaning of x86 - it refers to the predecessors of x64 (e.g. 16 bit, 32 bit). The reason why is explained well here https://serverfault.com/questions/188177/why-does-x86-represent-32bit-when-x64-represents-64bit

Comment: `Click on "Windows x86 executable installer"` - well, you are getting exactly what you clicked on. Click on "Windows x86-64 executable installer" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.howtogeek.com/129178/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder/

> “x86” now refers to the pre-64-bit architecture—whether that’s 16-bit or 32-bit. The newer 64-bit architecture is referred to as “x64” instead.

So when you choose the "x86" installer you were given the 32-bit installer, but also could have been given a 16-bit installer if it existed.

It looks like your system has a 64-bit architecture so you should instead download and install the 64-bit version here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ (labeled x86-64)

Comment: In other contexts you may see the 32-bit x86 architecture called "ia-32". But "ia-64", on the other hand, is Itanium, not x86. You may see "x86-64" shortened as just "x64", or instead as "amd64". The 64-bit x86 architecture was originated by AMD back when Intel was trying to make Itanium catch on. Itanium never picked up momentum and will be discontinued in a couple years. Intel was forced to copy AMD.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you searched for `x-86 executable` . `x86` meant for `32bit`.
if you want to download for `64 bit` go through this [link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/python-3.7.4-amd64.exe).